# Use RouterFunction with embedded Eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, web-applications, reactive-programming, netflix-eureka, spring-webflux

I'm having an issue getting a simple web app using Spring Reactive's RouterFunction to work with an embedded Eureka server. I tried a couple of things, including using the old way of annotating @RestController which works fine. Furthermore, I tried to removing the Eureka dependency from the POM file after which the RouterFunction endpoint worked fine.

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>tds</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Router, that does not get hit:

```
@Configuration
public class Router {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(Handler handler) {
        return route(GET("/test"), Handler::handle);
    }
}
```

Controller, that get's hit fine:

```
@RestController
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public class controller {

    @GetMapping("/discovery")
    public String getApplication() {
        return "test2222";
    }
}
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(com.test.tds.DiscoveryApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

As stated above, after removing the dependency to Eureka the RouterFunction endpoint works fine.

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `Webflux` is currently not supported by `Eureka server`. It is suggested to use the old `spring-boot-starter-web` way.

As future reference:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3108#issuecomment-408262981